# Cannot read 'create' property of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I am following a tutorial on building an app with Express, Nodejs, Sequelize,Postgres.
After creating my controller and routes, the GET route works perfectly but POST route (mean to call a callback function for creating an object) fails with:

> TypeError: cannot read property 'create' of undefined.

This is the controller:

```
let Todo = require('../models').todo;

module.exports = {
    create(req, res){
        return Todo
        .create({title:req.body.title,})
        .then(todo => res.status(201).send(todo))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
    },
    list(req, res){
        return Todo
        .all()
        .then(todos => res.status(200).send(todos))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
    },
};
```

And this is the route definition

```
const todosController = require('../controllers').todos;


module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/api', (req, res) =>res.status(200).send({message:"welcome to the todos API!"}));
    app.post('/api/todos', todosController.create);
    app.get('/api/todos', todosController.list);
};
```

...and here is the todo model. Thanks @Yuri Tarabanko

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>{
  const Todo = sequelize.define('Todo', {
    title:{ 
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
  }, 
  {
    classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        Todo.hasMany(models.TodoItem,
          {
          foreignKey:'todoId',
          as: 'todoItems',
            
          });
          },
      },
    }
    );
  return Todo;
};
```

My `controllers/index.js` file is shown below.

```js
const todos = require('./todos');
module.exports = {
    todos,
};
```

Comment: Plz add `models` and `controllers` files. It seems the problem is with the way you reexport either `Todo` or `todoContoller`

Comment: I just did that now. Thanks @YuryTarabanko

Comment: You export `todo` model as factory function. Could you also add your code where you call this factory to create `Todo` model. `models/index.js` I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are importing wrong...

Change:

```
const todosController = require('../controllers').todos;
```

to

```
const todosController = require('../controllers/todos')
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be not

```
const todosController = require('../controllers').todos;
```

but

```
const todosController = require('../controllers');
```

because your `create` and `list` functions are not in `todo` but in root of `module.exports`.

> create and list functions are actually in the "todo.js" file in the
>   "controllers" directory.

Then you should require them as

```
const todosController = require('../controllers/todo');
```

unless you have `controllers/index.js` which has

```
modules.exports={todo:require(todo)};
```

Also note that your file seems to be called `todo`, not `todos`.

Comment: create and list functions are actually in the "todo.js" file in the "controllers" directory.

Comment: I actually have a 'controller/index.js' file. The content is appended to the question.

Comment: Everything seems fine then. Please copy here the value of `todosController` after you require it.